# htaccess URL Rewrite for products doesn't redirect me

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

There is plenty of information out there but nothing I've read on the interwebz has given me an answer as to why my htaccess is not working.

I cannot determine why my rule isn't rewriting the URL as I thought it would. I have the following url:

```
domain.com/Book/bookpage/index.php?bookID=123&bookName=foo_bar
```

I would like to change it so that when someone hits that URL, it shows like:

```
domain.com/Book/123/foo_bar
```

I started off trying to get it to work using just the Book ID and haven't even gotten that to work.

This is what I have thus far:

```
RewriteRule ^Book/([0-9]+)$    /Book/bookpage/index.php?bookID=$2
```

However, after placing that htaccess in the root of the site and going to the URL:

```
domain.com/Book/bookpage/index.php?bookID=123
```

The URL in the address bar remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# this rewrite domain.com/Book/123 or domain.com/Book/123/
RewriteRule ^Book/([0-9]+)/?$ /Book/bookpage/index.php?bookID=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

# this rewrite domain.com/Book/123/title or domain.com/Book/123/title/
RewriteRule ^Book/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /Book/bookpage/index.php?bookID=$1&bookName=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [L,R=301] at the end of the line:

```
RewriteRule ^Book/([0-9]+)$ /Book/bookpage/index.php?bookID=$2 [L,R=301]
```